# Remove flat rate shipping on orders above 1000$?

Tags: magento2, shipping

Is there any way to remove flat are shipping on orders, if their total is above 1000$?

I have to use flat rate on this site aswell, so I cant use the built in way of giving free shipping to orders, as it seems to apply only to normal shipping methods, and not flat rate.

Any help is more than welcome. Thank you!

Comment: did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it to override Flate rate model file.

```
vendor/magento-offline-shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php
```

change 79 line to

**Old**

```
if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }
```

**New**

```
if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active') || $request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() > 1000) {
            return false;
        }
```

***First do directly in vendor after it works then please override model. Don't forgot to override model file.**

Comment: I've updated the code, but now I cant checkout - I cant get past the /checkout/ page, and I dont see any errors, not in console, and no ajax requests are being made.

Comment: I have to remove the handling fee, not the price btw

Comment: Above code works for me fine. maybe you forgot to remove cache

Comment: above code olny works when your order amount greater then 1000 in  cart.